# the best way to refer answers from questions

Tags: django, security, django-forms

My project run in django all works fine, but I question the solution from identify the question that was answered, i usually have the next solution:

```
{% for question in questions %}
        <article>
            {{ question.user.first_name }} {{ question.user.last_name }}:
            {{ question.content }}
            from <strong>{{question.timestamp|timesince}}</strong>
            <form action="{% url 'answer' %}">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <input type="hidden" value="{{ question.id }}" id="fromQuestion"/>
                {{ formAnswer.as_p }}
            </form>
        </article>
        {% endfor %}
```

because the input #fromQuestion can be replaced with any value to an attack.
There is way to do this correctly

Comment: It may be because English is not your first language but I have a really hard time trying to decipher what you are saying / asking. Could you try to be more clear?

Comment: recognize that question is answered in the above solution is achieved with a hidden input containing the id of the question but I do not think that is the best solution because this value could be changed if any such question is defined for 1000 and is changed to the 1